# PHPExcel For loop data to array conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, phpexcel

I am attempting to convert data acquired via a For loop within a ForEach loop.
I am getting the data that I expected from the PHP code below. The problem is, when I try to convert it to an array (any method including explode), I only get the last result. I can tell by running the array request within the loop that I get repetitive information but outside the loop I only get the last result.

I am using PHPExcel. I am not using a file open because I am loading this array from the tmp file, prior to move file intentionally.

I am gathering the headers of any columns with data to build my array (to be loaded into a listbox next). I understand there is an extra comma, but that can be fixed once I can get it extracted properly.

The code below provides me the first 3 headers of my tmp file: "Header1,Header2,Header3," - This was altered from a previous search on building a table on the webpage from Excel.

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
$highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestDataRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestDataColumn(); // e.g 'F'
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
$nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
for ($row = 1; $row < 2; ++ $row) {
    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, 1);
        $val = $cell->getValue().',';
        $dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
print_r($val); //This is displaying what I expect to see "Header1,Header2,Header3,"
    }
}}
```

I have tried code like below (along with $myArray), but I get results like: `"Header1,Array ( [0] => Header1, ) Header2,Array ( [0] => Header2, ) Header3,Array ( [0] => Header3, )" or if outside the } "Array ( [0] => Header3, )`

```
$myString = $val;
$myArray = explode(',',$myString,0);
print_r($myArray);
```

Thank you for any help!

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace below line in for loop

$val = $cell->getValue().',';

with

$val .= $cell->getValue().',';

above line will concate your result one by one seperated by comma.

If you need all the in one array then replace below line

$myArray = explode(',',$myString,0);

with

$myArray = explode(',',$myString);